# can't implement the movement of 2d mechanism

Tags: java, user-interface, 2d, physics

I implement Chebyshev walking mechanism, like [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwitieDcjoTiAhVhw8QBHZ62D60QjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FChebyshev%2527s_Lambda_Mechanism&psig=AOvVaw2PwJeMlwe8FNtmN1hgGSwb&ust=1557136253318913)

And I've got a problem so the edges of the mech don't move like they're meant to

For now I have a GUI with some controls using Java8 Swing, it draws a mech, but movement is a problem as i said

[here](https://github.com/andpuc23/Kursach2/tree/master/src/mechanism/mechanics_swing/Edge.java) is my GitHub and the class with a problem method DFS_movement()

So I want this mech to move like the actual one with the constant lengths of the edges an all this stuff

Comment: You've only given us the binaries, not the code. And be more specific about what the "problem" is.

Comment: Meowgoesthehog, fixed the link. The problem exactly is that the mech is collapsing one edge and stretching another instead of moving them with constant length

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need the formulas, i.e. the equations of the position `(x,y)` of the end that moves (almost) along a straight line with respect to the rotation angle `a` (that describes the circular motion of the "first" bar)? Here the origin of the coordinate system is at the point of rotation of the first bar and the rotation angle `a` is the angle between the first bar and the horizontal x-axis. If that is the case, the equations are:

```
x = 2*A - 2*A*sqrt( (5 + cos(a))/(5 - 4*cos(a)) )*sin(a)

y = 2*A*sqrt( (5 + cos(a))/(5 - 4*cos(a)) )*(2 - cos(a))
```

`A` is the length of the first barm the one that rotates around its fixed end, attached to the origin of the coordinate system. The distance between the origin and the other fixed point of the linkage is 2A.